# Load External HTML and Add Event Handler for Element Declared in the HTML

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

I have a external HTML to be loaded after the main HTML is loaded.

```
<!--external.html-->
<form id="externalForm">
    <div id="button">Button</div>
</form>
```

How to add event handler for "button"?

Tried the following code in the main HTML,

```
<!--main.html-->
<body>
<div id="extForm"></div><!--to be loaded when document.ready-->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fill extForm with div's declared in external.html
    $("#extForm").load("external.html");
}
// button.ready will be triggered after loading external.html
$("#button").ready(handlerCreator());

var handlerCreator = function () {
   return function() {
       alert("Working"); // since button is ready
       $("#button").on("click", function() {
           alert("Not working"); // why?
       });
   };
}

</script>
```

Comment: You have to remove the brackets here: `$("#button").ready(handlerCreator);`

Comment: @Igle parenthesis != brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Button does not have a ready handler... you need to use event delegation

Use event delegation to register the handler for `#button`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#extForm").load("external.html");
})
$("#extForm").on('click', '#button', function () {
    alert('button clicked')
});
```

or register the handler after the external file is loaded to the dom

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#extForm").load("external.html", function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
            alert('button clicked')
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: But why does the first alert "Working" pop up?

Comment: @JeffreyGoines even though you are registering the ready handler to `button` it is same as adding it to the document so when the document is loaded the method returned by `handlerCreator` is executed